# Woocommerce custom product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am experienced with Wordpress, PHP etc but just finding my way around WooCommerce and looking for advice.I have developed a system where a user can upload a photo, pan, zoom, add text and save it. I am completely stuck on how exactly to go about adding this system to a product in WooCommerce on a product page. It does not effect the price etc its just so the customer can customize an image then order it for print. Any advice or guidance of the best go about this to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the image that is uploaded need to be associated with their order?

Comment: Yes and preferably become the image for the product once it has been generated.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a bit too involved for this site. I would start with the WooCommerce documentation and looking into the various actions and filters you can hook in to. Remember that a product/order is just a custom post type so you can use meta values.